# 405 Method even when posting to a php file

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I been googling, and all I can find is that this error may happen when you post to an html file. In my setup I have a rewrite rule, that basically hides the index.php from the url, and I for the longest time I thought it had something to do with that.
Get works fine.

> **Method Not Allowed**
>
> POST request is not allowed for the URL /post.php

Here is my setup:

```
Debian squeeze / AMD64

nginx version: nginx/1.1.8

PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 28 2011 08:24:40) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.32.1, Copyright (c) 2007-2010, by SektionEins GmbH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just solved this problem my self!

I installed lighttpd, and got the same error again with lighttpd as well.
I was looking at all the wrong places because the error 405 is a webserver error.

However, I just started using a new php framework called fatfree F3, and the error is being generated by this framework when you use GET like so:

```
F3::route('GET /autho/idreply', 'auth.php');
```

The GET means that the framework is expecting only GET variables and will reject POST variables.

**With a server error 405, that is!**

So changing that to, following did the trick:

```
F3::route('POST /auth/oidreply', 'auth.php');
```

And you can even let the framework accept both or either with this command;

```
F3::route('GET|POST /auth/oidreply', 'auth.php');
```